# Are there any Biology research classification systems?

Tags: research-tools

There are research classification systems for mathematics (MSC) and physics (PACS and subsequently PhySH) which help the researchers to navigate through codes composed by letters/numbers made by associations that specialise in those pieces of human knowledge. Are there any classification systems of research in Biology?

Comment: You need to explain what sort of classes these systems produce, who operates them, and in what circumstances, as they do not immediately convey anything to me.

Comment: These classes are made by big associations in a try to make a classification of a piece of human knowledge, for example in the case of Mathematics the American Mathematical Society has made an effort since the last century to classify all the Mathematical research areas into a "simple" system of classes where one can access all areas of Mathematics just by a system of numerical/letter codes.
These classes are usually updated from times to times due to human knowledge evolution.

Comment: I discourage people answering in comments, but when the answer is a simple 'no' it is difficult to provide rigorous documentation in support. There are obviously different disciplines that lead to different academic departments, and British and (I imagine) US grant authorities divide biology up for the purposes of targeting resources and assigning experts, but trying to make a classification would be like trying to catch a greased piglet.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.